# Raspberry Pi 3 B+: Many video devices are showing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, streaming-video, webcam

I attached two webcams to RaspberryPi 3B+ using USB power hub. But when I wrote `ls -la /dev/video*` in Terminal, output shows many video devices as shown below:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 5 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 6 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 4 Jun  7 12:28 /dev/video3
```

I think it should show two video devices only. Why it is showing multiple video devices? What is the meaning of `video10` etc?
While working, using `video0` and `video2`, camera get started. Why not camera get started with `video1`?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, BUT why don't you try to investigate it yourself? Try with no cameras, 1 camera etc. On my Pi3B+ I have no camera but `/dev/video10  /dev/video11  /dev/video12`

Comment: I already checked with No cameras and it shows 
`crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun 11 10:18 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jun 11 10:18 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Jun 11 10:18 /dev/video12`

Comment: It's remotely possible that your cameras are designed to expose themselves as more than one interface, and that your baseline case has some other driver loaded to appear as a camera. Use `v4l2-ctl -D --list-formats` on each device to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

They represent hardware encoders/decoders/pixel converters. You can observe their details with command

```
v4l2-ctl --all --device /dev/video*
```